# Promise only parsing about half the files in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, typescript, promise

I have the following function which processes a list of files. I am having an issue where only about half of the files execute this

```
treeBuilder.Parse(data, file).then(result => {
    // code
}
```

The others execute it successfully.

```
var docsToDo: string[] = [];
function processWorkspaceFile() {
    var offset: number = 0;
    docsToDo.forEach(file => {
        fq.readFile(file, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err, data) => {
            treeBuilder.Parse(data, file).then(result => {
                addToWorkspaceTree(result.tree);
                docsDoneCount++;
                connection.console.log(`(${docsDoneCount} of ${docsToDo.length}) File: ${file}`);
                connection.sendNotification({ method: "fileProcessed" }, { total: docsDoneCount });
                if (docsToDo.length == docsDoneCount) {
                    connection.console.log('work done!');
                    notifyClientOfWorkComplete();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

`treeBuilder.Parse()` returns a Promise, is it possible that the promise is getting overwritten?

```
public Parse(text:string, filePath:string) : Promise<any>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var ast = phpParser.create({
            parser: {
                locations: true,
                docBlocks: true,
                suppressErrors: true
            }
        }).parseCode(text);


        this.BuildObjectTree(ast, filePath).then((tree) =>
        {
            var symbolCache = this.BuildSymbolCache(tree, filePath).then(symbolCache =>
            {
                var returnObj = {
                    tree: tree,
                    symbolCache: symbolCache
                };

                resolve(returnObj);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For starters, you aren't checking the `err` value in the callback from `fq.readFile()`.  You also don't have a reject handler for `treeBuilder.Parse()`.  It should go without saying that you should always code for error handling and when things aren't working correctly, you should make sure you're looking at all error paths.  Coding in a way that ignores errors will certainly not show you what's going on when there are errors.

Comment: Which half?  First half?  Last half?  Every other?  Random?  I don't think the promise is being overwritten - your arrow function is creating a new callback each time.  The for() loop may be the problem?

Comment: Also, your `Parse()` function is using a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) and a main consequence of that anti-pattern is that you are ignoring errors that occur in `this.buildSymbolCache()`.  You should just be returning chained promises rather than creating your own promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code is ignoring errors in three separate places, it is hard for you to see where an error might be occurring.  Here are the three places you are ignoring errors:

1. If `this.BuildSymbolCache()` rejects, you are ignoring that rejection.
2. If `fq.readFile()` calls its callback with an error, you are ignoring that condition.
3. If `treeBuilder.Parse(data, file)` rejects, you are ignoring that rejection.

You MUST code for error handling.  And, whenever something is not working as suspected, you should be able to look at all possible error paths.

Also, your `Parse()` function is using a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) and a main consequence of that anti-pattern is that you are ignoring errors that occur in `this.buildSymbolCache()`.  You should just be returning chained promises rather than creating your own promise.

I don't know TypeScript myself, so you may have to fix up a few TypeScript syntax errors, but here's the general idea for something that pays attention to all errors.  Assuming you are attempting to run all your operations in parallel and just want to know when they are all done, you can do this:

```
// make promise version of readFile()
fq.readFileAsync = function(file, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fq.readFile(file, options, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

var docsToDo: string[] = [];
function processWorkspaceFile() {
    var offset: number = 0;
    var promises = [];
    return Promise.all(docsToDo.map(file => {
        return fq.readFileAsync(file, { encoding: 'utf8' }).then(data => {
            return treeBuilder.Parse(data, file).then(result => {
                addToWorkspaceTree(result.tree);
                docsDoneCount++;
                connection.console.log(`(${docsDoneCount} of ${docsToDo.length}) File: ${file}`);
                connection.sendNotification({ method: "fileProcessed" }, { total: docsDoneCount });
            });
        });
    })).then(notifyClientOfWorkComplete, function(err) {
       // error here, err contains the error value from the first error that occurred 
    });
}


public Parse(text:string, filePath:string) : Promise<any> {
    var ast = phpParser.create({
        parser: {
            locations: true,
            docBlocks: true,
            suppressErrors: true
        }
    }).parseCode(text);


    return this.BuildObjectTree(ast, filePath).then((tree) => {
        return this.BuildSymbolCache(tree, filePath).then(symbolCache => {
            return {tree: tree, symbolCache: symbolCache};
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Added code example that pays attention to all errors.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - stack overflow does not work very well when you modify the original code from your question to incorporate feedback you were given.  That renders answers and comments already provided as nonsensical because the answers and comments don't apply to the current version of the question.  Do NOT change the original question except to clarify what you are trying to ask.  That makes your question an entirely different question.  If you still have problems after trying suggested fixes, you can ADD new versions of code to your question, but don't change the original code you posted.

Comment: Sorry I misread your last line, I thought you asked me to update with the resolve/reject. I rolled back the question to is original state.